# Make a DeepLink url call for group chat

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I'm working on a Adaptive card in bot framework v3 using c#. On my Adaptive card I have created a AdaptiveShowCard action. In that show card I have binded a choice options which has a value of user email ID. On click of submit of that show card I have to initiate a group chat.

**Problem:** when submit button is clicked, I'm getting the values of email id's in Activity object, now i have to use that Id's and create a deeplink URL

**Challenge**: I'm unable to make a Deeplink url call from my message controller.

Code adaptiveshowcard:

```cs
 new AdaptiveShowCardAction()
                    {                     
                     Title = "Group chat",
                     Card = Groupchat // having choice structure 
                    },
```

Message controller:

```cs
 if (activity.Name == "composeExtension/onCardButtonClicked")
                {
                    try
                    {
                        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
                        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://teams.microsoft.com/l/chat/0/0?users=User@domain.onmicrosoft.com") as HttpWebRequest;
                        }
}
```

Please suggest how to initiate a group chat

Comment: Can you clarify what your issue is? Are you unable to initiate a group chat, unable to link to it, or both?